# Geostatistical Analyst raster export looks completely different

Tags: raster, arcgis-10.2, export, geostatistical-analyst

I'm having trouble trying to re-create how a Kriged layer looks when interpolated using Geostatistical Analyst. I like the level of generalization (smoothness) of the filled contours in the "temporary" GA layer prior to export, but when I "Export to Raster" I get a jagged pixelated raster.

It doesn't seem to make a difference whether I use a large (50m) or small (20m) cell size. Here's an example, with both the GA and raster layers at the same contour interval.

Are there other settings I should be changing for export?

Geostatistical layer (smooth contours):

[image: GA_20m]

Raster export (jagged contours):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

GA layers are a lower resolution and on-the-fly redrawn version of the interpolation results, that's why the output raster differs from the GA layer. As a result of this on-the-fly resampling, cell values from the GA layer can be different from the output raster's cells values. I advise you to read Esri's blog post [Understanding Geosatistical Analyst Layers](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2008/09/29/understanding-geostatistical-analyst-layers/) for more details.

If you want to reuse the GA layer symbology, the only way is probably to save it as a lyr file (Exporting the GA layer as a raster saves the actual - full resolution - result, not its layer representation).

Comment: My raster didn't seem to change at all when changing between Nearest Neighbour and Bilinear Interpolation (or Cubic).
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/B50lgJt.png">

Comment: I tested with the Kriging tool from Spatial Analyst and couldn't reproduce your issue, sorry. I could test with Geostatistical Analyst today, see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for my issue was Aggregating my exported raster 10x (from 50m cell size to 500m), then Sampling the aggregated raster. I used Topo to Raster to interpolate the sampled points, which gave me a similarly generalized raster to what Geostatistical Analyst produces.

Apparently the .lyr file from a GA layer can't be applied to an exported raster.